# What is Neil Patrick Harris drinking?

Tags: props, harold-and-kumar

In the movie [Harold & Kumar Escape from Guantanamo Bay](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0481536/) approximately one hour in, Neil Patrick Harris is driving a car. He picks up a bottle and takes a long swig. His hand is covering up a nontrivial amount of the label, making it difficult to read.

What is printed on the label of the bottle?

Please note that I understand this is a movie prop and it is not a real bottle that would be sold in a liquor store. It is clearly meant to look like a bottle of Jack Daniels whiskey, but with obvious alterations to avoid allegations of product placement or trademark infringement. However, given the propensity for some TV and movie props to have humorous content, I am curious what is on the bottle.

It appears to say "Jim D... Kentucky Cold Mash Whiskey" which appears to be a spoof on "Jack Daniels Tennessee Sour Mash Whiskey" but it is unclear exactly what the name is at the top as well as what some of the smaller text says.

---

[image: The bottle from which NPH is drinking]

Comment: It appear to be a spoof label mimicking the Jack Daniels label and the Jim Beam name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name at the bottom appears to read "Jim Danger Distillery". Probably a spoof on Jim Beam Distillery which makes a Kentucky Bourbon Whiskey.